# Convert String into Class reference

Tags: java, string, class, reference

I want to know if someone know how to convert a String like this into a Class reference.

I think that this example is enough to understand why Im asking

```
String className = "MainClass";
if(annotation instanceof className)
```

The idea is to use the String as a reference of a class, like if the name of my class is "MainClass.java" I can create that comparation of "instanceof" with a string that contain the name of the class but this is a mistake in code, because instanceof is a comparation of an object with an specific class

Some help?
Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the language you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `Class.forName(String)` method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

That will return a `Class<?>` instance, which you can then use to check if your object is an instance of, like so:

```
final Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(classNameString);
return myClass.isInstance(myObject);
```